# Values always do not tally

Tags: c, getline

I'm relatively new to C programming and I am trying to code a program that reads in a user's marks and assign a grade to the mark inputted.
I have used the `getline()` function to acquire user input. Below is my code.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <ctype.h>

int getMark();
void display(char grade);
char convert(int mark);

int getMark() {
    do {
        int marks;
        char * buffer;
        char characters;
        size_t bufsize = 16;

        buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
        if( buffer == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
        exit(1);
        }

        printf("Enter the score (0 - 100)\nOr just press the enter key to quit ==> ");
        characters = getline(&buffer, & bufsize, stdin);
        int i;
        long check;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == '\n' && i != 0) {
                buffer[i] = '\0';
            }

            if (isdigit(buffer[i]) || buffer[i] == '\0') {
                check++;
            }
        }

        if (buffer[0] == '\n') {
            return -1;
        } else if (check == strlen(buffer) - 1) {
            marks = atoi(buffer);
        } else {
            printf("Please enter an integer.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (marks >= 0 && marks <= 100) {
            return marks;
        } else {
            printf("Sorry, your marks can only be between 0 to 100.\n");
            continue;
        }

    } while (1);
}

void display(char grade) {
    printf("The grade for the input score is %c \n", grade);
}

char convert(int mark) {
    mark /= 10;
    char grade;

    switch(mark) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        grade = 'F';
        break;
        case 4:
        grade = 'E';
        break;
        case 5:
        grade = 'D';
        break;
        case 6:
        grade = 'C';
        break;
        case 7:
        grade = 'B';
        break;
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
        grade = 'A';
    }

    return grade;
}

int main() {
    int marks;
    for (;;) {
        marks = getMark();
        if (marks == -1) {
            break;
        }
        display(convert(marks));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I press *Enter*, the program exits, as expected.
However, when an integer is entered, for example `12`, the output will always be `Please enter an integer.`

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char * buffer;
...
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
    if (buffer[i] == '\n' && i != 0) {
```

`sizeof(buffer)` returns the size of a *pointer to char* (4 or 8 bytes depending on the architecture), not the length of the string, in consequence, you are reading outside of the bounds of the array when `12` is entered.

Change to `strlen()` or better yet, use the result of `getline`:

> On success, getline() and getdelim() return the number of characters
>   read, including the delimiter character, but not including the
>   terminating null byte ('\0').